# Creating an extended, community cultivated FAQ on Meta

Tags: discussion, faq-content

The site's [FAQ](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq) is important but intentionally terse; Meta is better for fleshing out supporting arguments and finer points, but it's a pain to find.

The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag is meant to help make sort of a long-form FAQ on Meta, one we could link to (linking to the tag actually, or a question compiling FAQ entries).

Should we start compiling some FAQ questions on Meta? Do we have any existing posts that would be useful? Are there trip-ups common enough for this to be useful?

For the record, if you see a Meta post that's important enough to be an [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) question, go ahead and flag it and explain that. The [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag can only be added by moderators.

Comment: Great idea to crowdsource adding the FAQ tag to meta posts! :) +1

Answer (score 5):

I'd say yes, absolutely!  I'm actually thinking I'd tag about half the stuff on meta as useful for the FAQ as we have  alot of "should this be considered on topic" type discussions here.

Comment: Probably many of our [meta-tag:on-topic-definition] questions you  mean?

Comment: yes - that's exactly the subset I was thinking of!

Answer (score 4):

The close voting guide should definitely be included, and highlight the fact that the privilege threshold is lowered, not just in points, but also in the list of privileges, to give more community members the power to help keep the site clean and on-topic.

In other words, the order in which you gain privileges on a beta site is different, you get close/reopen vote privileges before you even get full editing permissions, unlike a graduated site.

In my experience, there are likely to be some 500+ rep users who don't realize they can vote to close/reopen, and it could be helpful to make them aware of this in the expanded FAQ.

Comment: This one? http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/140/a-guide-to-moderating-workplace-stackexchange-com-yourself-close-voting

Comment: Yes @Rarity. That's the one! :)